# SVG not showing on godaddy WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, svg

I uploaded my site to godaddy after working on it locally and now all the SVGs are showing as code not images. The only thing I got to make it work is adding

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
```

to the htaccess file. The probalm with that is it then breaks my site links in wordpress. When I reset the permalinks to fix that the svg's dont work again. Not sure why. Here is what my access file looks like.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. I had to put that rule outside the #wordpress part like so:

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```